# Inherit from two parent class (which inherit from one base class) but some methods don't work

Tags: c++, class, multiple-inheritance

i have troubles with some methods after inherit.
It's hard (for me) to say where exactly problem is but i will try to expose this by example.

Minimal code:

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    A() {};
    A(int x):val(x)
    {
        std::cout << "A constructor work" << std::endl;
    }

    int get()
    {
        std::cout << "Get A work" << std::endl;
        return val;
    }

protected:
    int val; 
};

class B: protected A
{
public:
    B(int x) :A(x) 
    {
        std::cout << "B constructor work" << std::endl;
        test();
    }

    int get()
    {
        std::cout << "Get B work" << std::endl;
        return A::get();
    }

protected:
    void test()
    {
        if (A::val == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Test B work" << std::endl;
            A::val = 1;
        }
    }

};

class C : protected A
{
public:

    C() {};
    C(int x) :A(x)
    {
        std::cout << "C constructor work" << std::endl;
        test();
    }

    int get()
    {
        std::cout << "Get C work" << std::endl;
        return A::get();
    }
protected:
    void test()
    {
        std::cout << "Test C work" << std::endl;

        if (A::val != 0)
        {
            A::val += 2;
        }
    }

};

class D : private B, private C
{
public:
    D(int x):B(x)
    {
        std::cout << "D constructor work" << std::endl;
        C::test();
    }

    int get()
    {
        std::cout << "Get D work" << std::endl;
        return B::get();
    }

};


int main()
{
    D d(0);

    std::cout << d.get() << std::endl;
}
```

```
Output: 
**A constructor work
B constructor work
Test B work
D constructor work
Test C work
Test C extra work
Get D work
Get B work
Get A work
1**
```

I expect val = 3 in the end, but it dont work like that. 
I would be particularly grateful for your detailed reply.

Comment: What "detailed reply" are you looking for? Do you not understand the results, or you understand the results, but are asking how to implement different behavior, and if so exactly what behavior are you looking for? You need to explain, in detail, what exactly you are asking, it's hard to tell.

Comment: As i wrote, i expect val = 3 in the end but it's equal to 1 
despite the function test from class C was used.

Comment: Oh, i don't know about something like that, so how can i connect them or is any other way to solve this?

Comment: Why do you use chaining up here: `return A::get();`? `val` is a `protected` member so your derived classes inherit it thus you can use directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `class D` contains two `A` objects - the one inherited by `B` and the one inherited by `C`

When you call `C::test()` you change the `A` object in `C`.

When you call `D::get()` - which calls `B::get()` - you inspect the value of the `A` object in `B`.

---

One way to get around this is by means of [virtual inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance).  That is not something you want to mess with until you understand how multiple inheritance works, though.

Comment: I will trying this, but i would like to use something else (for now i don't have many knowledges about virtual constructors and other), anyway thanks for response.